# What is the meaning of "transcipher" (if such term exists)

Tags: encryption

recently I heard the term "transcipher" during a discussion (seems something related to double encryption using two different keys), but I was not able to find any information about such a term in the internet. Is it an actual cryptography term? if so, what does it mean?

Comment: Maybe similar to "transcode" - to decode one format, then re-encode in another format.

Answer (score 4):

It's decryption with one key and encrypting with another key as a single operation, without looking at the contents.

Answer (score 3):

It is a command of the german health card.
See [here](https://fachportal.gematik.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachportal/files/Spezifikationen/Basis-Rollout/Elektronische_Gesundheitskarte/gematik_eGK_Spezifikation_Teil1_V2_2_0.pdf) for the RSA version. There exists also  an ECC version for the generation 2 card. The specification is also on the [www.gematik.de](http://www.gematik.de) web site but its a bit tricky to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "transcipher" is just a short term for "transposition cipher".
Don't know if you looked that up already ([reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher)).

Basically it's reordering the units composing a plaintext.

If that didn't help, could you provide more infomation on the context of that discussion you're referring to?

Answer (score -1):

Simple and actually common word between both intel ops and archeological decryption.

Transcipher vs decrypt.

Decrypt: remove encryption.

Transcipher:

1. decrypt something that needed to be decrypted but not because it was meant to be encrypted in the first place. and. In most cases, the encryption nore the contents actually exist. Therefore, nothing is ever actually decrypted because   all the constituents non-exists in a reified non-solid unflexible state.(subjectivity does not exists. Words are only representations of: consensus extrapolation(transciphering , and a touch of madness. Nothing is actually changed or destroyed in the process called "decryption." Whatever it was that was encrypted remains "encypted." You merely found a way to [i]read[/i] it. The contents of the encrypted packet and how to read it.
2. a change between a state of being "stuck" to "free" of encryption as an obstacle to a held perspective/s.
   2.1) a change between being either "stuck" or "free" of encryption as an obstacle to a held perspective/s.
3. worm jumping a fence.
4. you have now transciphered all sense of a word thats used to talk about doing that.